# selectors from getSelectors returning empty array in rtk query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using redux toolkit in which I have created a api slice as below, But when I try to use the selectors generated from getSelectors it always returns an empty array even though the hook returns data which is populated from the api response

songs slice:

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { convertObjectToCamelCase } from "@utils";
import { itunesApiService } from "@utils/apiUtils";

type Params = {
  searchTerm: string;
  offset: number;
  limit: number;
};

const songsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (track: any) => track.trackId,
});

const initialState = songsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const songsApi = itunesApiService.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    fetchSongs: builder.query<any, object>({
      query: (params: Params) => {
        if (!params.searchTerm || !params.offset || !params.limit) {
          throw new Error("Invalid params");
        }

        return `search?term=${params.searchTerm}&offset=${params.offset}&limit=${params.limit}`;
      },
      transformResponse: (response: any) => {
        return songsAdapter.setAll(initialState, response.results);
        // return convertObjectToCamelCase<any>(response);
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
        { type: "Track", id: "LIST" },
        ...result.ids.map(id => ({ type: "Track", id })),
      ],
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});

export const { useFetchSongsQuery } = songsApi;

export const selectSongsResult: any = songsApi.endpoints.fetchSongs.select({
  searchTerm: "new song",
  offset: 0,
  limit: 10,
});

const selectSongsData = createSelector(selectSongsResult, songResult => songResult.data);

export const {
  selectAll: selectAllSongs,
  selectById: selectSongById,
  selectIds: selectSongIds,
} = songsAdapter.getSelectors((state: any) => selectSongsData(state) ?? initialState);
```

Ui code:

```
import { Container } from "@common";
import SongsList from "@features/songs/components/SongsList";
import { Input, Pagination, Affix } from "antd";
import { IntlShape, injectIntl } from "react-intl";
import React, { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { debounce } from "lodash-es";
import { compose } from "redux";
import {
  useFetchSongsQuery,
  selectAllSongs,
  selectSongIds,
} from "@app/features/songs/api/getItunesSongs";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

interface SongContainerProps {
  intl: IntlShape;
}

const { Search } = Input;

export const Songs: React.FC<SongContainerProps> = ({ intl }) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>("");
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(0);

  const limit = 10;

  useEffect(() => {
    const offset = currentPage * limit;

    setOffset(offset);
  }, [currentPage]);

  const { error, isLoading, isFetching, isSuccess } = useFetchSongsQuery({
    searchTerm,
    offset,
    limit,
  });

  const data = useSelector(selectAllSongs);

  console.log("Data: ", data, isFetching);

  const handleOnChange = debounce((e: any) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setCurrentPage(1);
    if (value) {
      setSearchTerm(value);
    }
  }, 500);

  const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    setSearchTerm(value);
  };

  const handlePageChange = (page: any, pageSize: any) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <Container
      padding={20}
      maxwidth={1000}
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Search
        placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "song_search" })}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        data-testid="search-input"
      />
      <SongsList loading={isFetching} data={data} error={error} />
      {data && (
        <Affix offsetBottom={0}>
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              padding: "10px 0px",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Pagination
              defaultCurrent={1}
              total={50}
              onChange={handlePageChange}
              style={{ marginTop: "10px auto" }}
            />
          </div>
        </Affix>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default compose(injectIntl, memo)(Songs);
```

Here data is always shows an empty array instead it should return the response as a array from the api

Api slice:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { ApisauceInstance, create } from "apisauce";
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";
import snakeCase from "lodash/snakeCase";
import isomorphicFetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { mapKeysDeep } from "./index";

const apiClients: Record<string, ApisauceInstance | null> = {
  itunes: null,
  default: null,
};
export const getApiClient = (type = "itunes") => apiClients[type];
export const generateApiClient = (type = "itunes") => {
  switch (type) {
    case "itunes":
      apiClients[type] = createApiClientWithTransForm(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ITUNES_URL);
      return apiClients[type];
    default:
      apiClients.default = createApiClientWithTransForm(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ITUNES_URL);
      return apiClients.default;
  }
};

export const createApiClientWithTransForm = (baseURL: string) => {
  const api = create({
    baseURL,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
  api.addResponseTransform(response => {
    const { ok, data } = response;
    if (ok && data) {
      response.data = mapKeysDeep(data, keys => camelCase(keys));
    }
    return response;
  });

  api.addRequestTransform(request => {
    const { data } = request;
    if (data) {
      request.data = mapKeysDeep(data, keys => snakeCase(keys));
    }
    return request;
  });
  return api;
};

/**
 * @desc Here we initialize an empty api service that we'll inject endpoints into later as needed
 */
export const itunesApiService = createApi({
  reducerPath: "itunes",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ITUNES_URL,
    fetchFn: isomorphicFetch,
  }),
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath];
    }
  },
  tagTypes: ["Track"],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { useDispatch, TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import songReducer from "./slices/songs";
// import { recommendationsApi } from "@features/repos/api/getRecommendations";
// import { repoInfoApi } from "@features/info/api/getRepoInfo";
import middlewares from "./middlewares";
import { songsApi } from "@app/features/songs/api/getItunesSongs";
import { trackInfoApi } from "@app/features/info/api/getTrackInfo";
import { itunesApiService } from "@app/utils/apiUtils";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [itunesApiService.reducerPath]: itunesApiService.reducer,
    // [songsApi.reducerPath]: songsApi.reducer,
    // [trackInfoApi.reducerPath]: trackInfoApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(middlewares),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your selector by executing `songsApi.endpoints.fetchSongs.select();`

That is the selector for one explicit cache entry: the cache entry of `useFetchSongsQuery()` without arguments.

If you want to have a selector for `useFetchSongsQuery(someArgument)`, you also have to create the selector with that same argument - calling `songsApi.endpoints.fetchSongs.select(someArgument);`

Comment: It still returns an empty array even though the ids and entities are there

Comment: And you call it with exactly the same argument as you call your hook? With the same searchTerm, the same offset and the same limit?

Comment: Yes, I passed some default values for those params, I also added the api client as well as the store for more info

Comment: If you updated the examples, I can still not see you passing any argument into the `.select(...)` call.

Comment: Ok I updated it as well

Comment: As long as you are calling *exactly* `useFetchSongsQuery({ searchTerm: "new song", offset: 0, limit: 10 });` in your application, that should return that data then. If you use any other searchTerm, offset or limit than that, it will return an uninitialized result.
But it will also never return something that you can just use `entityAdapter.getSelectors` on. Have you ever tried executing that selector and logging what you get back without wrapping it? (also: don't type it as `any`, just don't specify a type and you'll have the right type!)

Comment: Is there a way to create memoize selectors and have dynamic parameters as well?, The hook returns data but it is in the form {ids : [...], entities: { id : {...}}}, The selector should return an filled array right?

Comment: The selector will return exactly the same as the hook. That's probably why applying `entityAdapter.getSelectors` doesn't give you anything - you should apply it to `selector(state).data`. You can do the same thing with the hook and `selectFromResult` though.